# Access to methods class in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

I have class that generate some js. Where i should put this class and how call methods from it in views?

```
class Hits
   @@config = Settings.statistic

   class << self
      def js_counter
         if @@config.enable
            ...
         end
      end
   end  
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have the class << part in there?

Comment: Sorry, `self`. I have edited post

Comment: Because I need many static methods here

Answer (score 1):

put it in the lib folder and require it in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Put class to **models** directory if you want.

In a view:

```
<%= javascript_tag Hits.js_counter.html_escape $>

# if js_counter returns String
```